# Skype API does not trigger event when call status changed

Tags: c#, skype

I am using the Skype API in my application.
Recently, with the new versions of Skype, the API has stopped triggering the the StatusChanged event.
If I Uninstall Skype and install an older version it works (until the next automatic upgrade)
Has anybody encounter this and knows how to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm they changed their API in recent versions regarding call status changes updating.

I have the following code to detect active Skype calls (Delphi):

```pascal
  ActiveCalls := Skype.ActiveCalls;
    if ActiveCalls.Count > 0 then
    begin
      for i := 1 to ActiveCalls.Count do
      begin
        call := ActiveCalls.Item[i];
        if call.Status = clsInProgress then
```

call.Status always returns 0 in Skype versions starting from 6.22. For older versions, it correctly reflects the current call status.